# Pylons: Proper Way to Establish Per-Thread/Per-Request Resource?

Tags: python, pylons

I have a connection to an external resource that I need to make for my Pylons app (think along the lines of a database connection.) There is a modest amount of overhead involved in establishing the connection.

I could setup a piece of middleware that opens and closes the connection with every request but that seems wasteful. I'd like to establish a connection for each new thread that starts up and save myself the overhead. How do I hook into thread startup in Pylons?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Do the connections have to belong to a single thread for their lifetime?

If not, you could consider implementing your own connection pool for this resource.  The pool would be responsible for initializing connections and each thread would `acquire` and `release` the connections as they are needed.

If you want to limit the number of available connections, you just block during the acquire phase until a connection is released or some timeout is reached.

The code to implement such a pool is going to be very dependent on the resource you are talking about, so it would be difficult to give you anything other than a suggested API.

Comment: No, they don't have to belong to the same thread, now that I think about it, as long as they are consistent for the duration of a request. As long as I have num_connections >= num_threads, I'd be OK. Any idea how to get the number of threads running?

Comment: Actually - I could just have my acquire method create new connections on demand, up to some limit. I will investigate this, thanks!

Comment: I don't think Pylons controls that, but is determined by whatever is hosting your WSGI container, be it Apache/mod_wsgi or other, so not sure if there is a 'portable' way to do it.  

However, if you design the connection pool correctly, your application would function properly for any num_connections >= 1 regardless of num_threads.  Each thread would just block until a connection became available.  (Making a couple of assumptions there, but generally speaking)

Then it would just be a matter of finding the sweet spot where you have enough connections in the pool to ensure minimal blocking.